# Apache 301 redirect in vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, url, virtualhost, 301-redirect, rewritecond

I wish to redirect(301) a url if the url dont have a string present in it.

eg:

http:://example.com must always redirected to http:://example.com/en

http:://example.com/test.html must always redirected to http:://example.com/en/test.html

http:://example.com/test/another_page must always redirected to http:://example.com/en/test/another_page

like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule /(.*) /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```